# Ошибка в подсчёте кликов

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Нужно, чтобы при условии, если переменная `informer` равна `0`, значение `id` элемента записывалось в `sfId_Star`. А когда `informer` равно `1`, то в `sfId_Target`.

Но у  меня почему-то пропускает один клик и записывает со второго. Подскажите, где я ошибся?

```
$(function() {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var informer = 0;
        var sfId_Start
        var  sfId_Target

        console.log(informer)

        $('td').click(function(){
            init()
            ++informer;
            if (informer >  1) {informer = 0}
            //  if (informer === 1 ) {   }
            console.log(informer)
        });

        function init(){

            $('td').click(function() {
                getId(this);
            });

            function getId(obj) {
                var  idsf
                if (informer === 0 ) {idsf = $(obj).attr('id')  }
                if (informer  === 1 && informer !== 0  ) {idsf = $(obj).attr('id') }

                sfId_Start = idsf
                sfId_Target = idsf
            }
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: Зачем вам Init и в нем еще одно навешивание события на клик? В этом то и проблема.

Comment: @IonDen Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вам Init и в нем еще одно навешивание события на клик? В этом то и проблема.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.

Comment: Вообще-то это есть в комментах.